# How can I uninstall all packages from a particular org as quickly and simply as possible?

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, cli, uninstall

How can I clean my org and uninstall all packages from a particular org as quickly and simply as possible?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are only 2GMP packages installed in the org, and no unmanaged components refer the package components, the following simple script can be used:

```
for OUTPUT in $(sfdx force:package:beta:installed:list --json | jq '.result [] .SubscriberPackageVersionId'  -r)
do
    sfdx force:package:uninstall -w 500 -p  $OUTPUT
done
```

Otherwise you need to resolve dependencies first.
For the 1GMP, it is possible to try to generate a `destructiveChanges.xml` with InstalledPackage metadata component.